# When using google sign in Flutter how to obtain user already in firebase or not?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

When using Google Signin how to check user is already in Firebase or not.Below is my all methods related firebase authentication.

```
class AuthServices {
  //firebase instance
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  //create a user from firebase user with uid
  UserModel? _userWithFirebaseUserUid(User? user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //create the stream for checking the auth changes in the user
  Stream<UserModel?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userWithFirebaseUserUid);
  }


//This is for google sign in
  Future handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        print('User is signed in');
        print('Display Name: ${googleSignInAccount!.displayName}');
        print('Email: ${googleSignInAccount!.email}');
        print('Profile Picture: ${googleSignInAccount!.photoUrl}');
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

        final UserCredential authResult =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final User? user = authResult.user;
        return _userWithFirebaseUserUid(user);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error during Google sign-in: $error");
    }
  }

  //Sign in anonymous
  Future signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userWithFirebaseUserUid(user);
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //register using email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userWithFirebaseUserUid(user);
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //signin using email and password
  Future signInUsingEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userWithFirebaseUserUid(user);
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }



  //signout
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

If user is already in firebase then user want to navigate Home page.If user is not in firebase then user navigate to getting details page.Using above handleGoogleSignIn() method I can't check whether user is in Firebase or not.Every time I click using same email then user login as same user Id.I want to check if user is in already Firebase or not and then navigate to correct page.

When google sign in if I used below code is it correct?I want to know is there any way to do this.

```
UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: googleSignInAccount!.email, password: googleSignInAccount!.id);
```

Below is my userModel class.

```
class UserModel{
  final uid;
  UserModel({required this.uid});


  factory UserModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return UserModel(
        uid: snapshot['uid']);
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson()=>{
    "uid":uid,
  };
}
```

For more info I inserted my login and register buttons' ontap functions below :-

Login Button :-

```
onPressed: () async {
                      dynamic result = await 
                      _auth.signInUsingEmailAndPassword(email,password);
                      if (result == null) {
                          setState(() {
                              error ="Could not sign in with those credential";
                          });
                      }
                   }
```

Register Button :-

```
onPressed: ()async {
                     widget.isPressed();
                     dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
                     password);
                     if (result == null) {
                         setState(() {
                             error = "Please enter a valid email!";
                         });
                     }
                   }
```

This 'widget.isPressed();' code is use to navigate getting details page when register.

I searched this is everywhere and could not find Flutter/Firebase help.So please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I could solve this problem. When Google signs,we can check whether or not the email is in Firebase. That is the way I used it.

Below is my updated handleGoogleSignIn() method.

```
Future handleGoogleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn();

      List<String> signInMethods = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(googleSignInAccount!.email);
      if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
        final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
        final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
          idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        );

        final UserCredential authResult =
            await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      }

      if (signInMethods.contains("google.com")) {
        print("Email is already associated with a Google Sign-In account.");
        return "0";
      } else {
        print("Email is not associated with any account.");
        return "1";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print("Error during Google sign-in: $error");
    }
  }
```

Below is my google signing button ontap method.

```
onTap: () async{
                  final user = await _auth.handleGoogleSignIn();
                  if(user == "0"){
                      print('Logged in');
                  }else if(user == "1"){
                      widget.isPressed();
                      print('Registered');
                  }else{
                      print('Sign-in failed.');
                  }
                }
```